# Ampersand.js and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ampersand.js

I've looked everywhere but cannot find any info on how to use ampersand.js to connect to a database (ideally mongodb). Can anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial or examplerepo?

Comment: Normally nobody does this, why would you want it? Because ampersand.js is a frontend tool, and mongodb is in the backend. Normally, you don't want to give your frontend a direct access to your DB. Or you do?

Comment: Connect how? Looking for any particular structure? I have some examples using ampersand.js -> node.js REST HTTP API -> mongodb. There's usually a need for something more in-between to connect your frontend and your DB.

Comment: @JAntunes this is right appraoch.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to establish connection and query a mongoDB instance via JavaScript, not necessary has to be using Ampersand.js.

[machinepack-mongodb](http://node-machine.org/machinepack-mongodb) is one example implementation to help you handles the database communication using node machine.